# Select previous different value PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have a table:

| id | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 3 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 3 |

I want to detect changing of *value* column by date:

| id | date | value | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 3 | 2 |

I tried a window function lag(), but all I got:

| id | date | value | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-01 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-03 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2022-01-04 | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 2022-01-06 | 3 | 3 |

Comment: Show your table definition (CREATE TABLE script), Postgres version, and the query you tried. And are values strictly ascending like your sample suggests?

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have to do a gaps-and-islands to "group" your changes.

There may be a more concise way to get the result you want, but this is how I would solve this:

```
with changes as ( -- mark the changes and lag values
  select id, date, value, 
         coalesce((value != lag(value) over w)::int, 1) as changed_flag,
         lag(value) over w as last_value
    from a_table
  window w as (partition by id order by date)
), groupnums as ( -- number the groups, carrying the lag values forward 
  select id, date, value, 
         sum(changed_flag) over (partition by id order by date) as group_num,
         last_value
    from changes
  window w as (partition by id order by date)
) -- final query that uses group numbering to return the correct lag value
select id, date, value, 
       first_value(last_value) over (partition by id, group_num
                                         order by date) as diff
  from groupnums;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9e5d844390935ced388e55a2908e48d1)*